# Pronunciation of ¡ (inverted exclamation mark, historically used for subfactorial)

Tags: soft-question, notation

**For anyone who uses ¡ (inverted exclamation mark) in a mathematical context, how do you pronounce it?**

Background: I have privately been using ¡ in a couple of notations for a while, and am considering using it in a paper. One of my reservations about doing so is pronouncability: it isn’t standardly used for anything in the areas I work in, so if I use it in print, I’ll give a suggested pronunciation (incidentally, something I wish more authors would do when introducing notations for which there’s not an obvious/established reading).

The only existing usage I have found mentioned is as an old (?obsolete) notation for subfactorial.  But, as an easily recognisable and available symbol, I guess it has probably been co-opted by other mathematicians on occasion.

For what it’s worth, I pronounce it to myself as “gnab”.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, couldn't the (mathematical) pronunciation be more related to the operation it represents and not the punctuation mark itself. For example, we pronounce $5!$ as "five factorial", not "five exclamation mark" or "five bang". We pronounce $\nabla f$ as "del eff" (although I think I might have heard some pronounce it "nabla eff").

Comment: What's its name in Spanish?  Probably there are also colloquial Spanish names as well.

Comment: GNAB = GNAB, Not A Bang

Comment: Does it appear before the main actor or after? As subscript or superscript?

Comment: I agree with mhum. For example, in my field ! is often pronounced "shriek" and ¡ is, in a similar context, pronounced "antishriek."

Comment: @Lubin: either as a main actor, as in $¡_X$, or as a prefix, $¡X$.

Comment: Maybe the opposite of shriek would be shrug.

Comment: Gasp? Gulp? Sob? Whimper?